# Getting Android screen size type during runtime (drawable-small, drawable-normal, etc)

Tags: android, android-resources

As explained in [Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) Android supports setting different images for different sizes of the screen by putting them in separate folders (drawable-small, drawable-normal, drawable-large and drawable-xlarge).

Is it possible to get the "type" of the screen that Android is using to load the resources during runtime? I need to log this variable for error reporting and it would help a lot if I can tell which drawable type folder system is using (similarly to how I can tell if it is ldpi, mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi by querying getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the "type" of the screen that Android is using to load the resources during runtime?

`getResources().getConfiguration()` gives you a `Configuration` object, and from there you can examine [the `screenLayout` field](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenLayout). This tells you size, long/not-long, and direction (LTR or RTL).